# Is $\vec{0}$ a geodesic? (specifically in $\Bbb{R}^3$ but also in the general case)

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

In my introductory differential geometry course (in which we only really dealt with $\Bbb{R}^3$ apart from some 'asides' to give context and to give some intuition about generalising some concepts for the future), we briefly covered geodesics in the last week of term. The definition given was as follows:

Let $M \subset \Bbb{R}^3$ be a surface, with $U$ a unit normal vector field on $M$,

$\alpha \colon I \to M$, such that $\alpha$ is smooth, is a geodesic if:

$\forall t \in I$, $\alpha''(t)$ is parallel to $U(\alpha(t))$.

Given this definition, it strikes me that $\vec{0}$ should be considered a geodesic, since $\vec{0}$ is considered parallel to every vector, and as such, setting $\alpha = \vec{0}$ gives us that $\alpha''(t) = \vec{0}$ and thus $\vec{0} \parallel U(\alpha(t)) = \vec{0}$.

It also strikes me that, given a geodesic is also described informally in my course as the shortest path between two points on a surface in $\Bbb{R}^3$, it is somewhat necessary to consider the zero vector as a geodesic, as it is of course always the shortest path between any point and the point itself

Is this true? If not, where have I gone astray in my reasoning? Furthermore, does this generalise to every geometric space? (Intuitively, it seems to me that it should)

Comment: You might be able to make some sense out of this, but as it is you're calling a single vector a path, and those are two different things.

Comment: @JonathanZ ah yes I see the issue here, so really the zero vector isn't a geodesic, but the **path** $\alpha (t) \equiv 0$ would be ?

Comment: Yup. It's possible some definitions of geodesic explicitly rule out such trivial paths, but without such a limitation it would be.

Comment: @JonathanZ ok thanks for this! What is my best option now, should I edit my post to make it about $\alpha (t) \equiv 0$ (I'm assuming not because the comments underneath will make no sense) or should I let you post an answer for me to accept, or should I post an answer myself including the context of your comment?

Comment: Going forward, it's perfectly fine for a poster to update their question based on comments, and then a conscientious user would then delete those comments. But people are used to seeing superseded comments and know how to "read around" them. But with this particular question, it would basically become pointless if you did such an update, So I went ahead and wrote up our comments as an answer. You could have done so too, although the usual practice is to wait a while before self-answering, and if the commenter hasn't written an answer by then, the OP might.

Comment: $U(\alpha(t))$ is most definitely *not* $\vec 0$.

Comment: It is common in mathematics to formulate definitions so as to *exclude* edge cases which require special treatment or whose incorporation would cause important properties to be violated. For example, I disagree with your statement that *$\vec 0$ is considered parallel to every vector*: the relation of parallelism should be formulated as a nontrivial equivalence relation, and for this reason it should be defined as a relation *only* amongst nonzero vectors.

Comment: @JonathanZ thanks for the additional context and the answer!

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for the additional context your comment provides. I have read in a few places, including this website, that $\vec{0}$ is considered parallel to every vector. Of course, I have also read plenty of other definitions for lines and vectors being parallel which exclude the zero case by default. Nonetheless, I do understand and agree that what you're saying is much more practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question is written you're calling a single vector a path, and those are two different things.

It would be correct if you defined a  **path** $\alpha(t) = x_0 \forall t$, i.e. a constant path. Any such $\alpha$ would be a geodesic. Note that it is possible for some definitions of geodesic to explicitly rule out such trivial paths, but without such a limitation it would be.